# Counting comments per object in `models.py` with Django's comments framework

Tags: python, django, django-models

I know in templates you can easily count comments with [`get_comment_count`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/comments/#counting-comments), but how can you get the same count as a method inside a class in `models.py`?

For example

```
class Blog( models.Model ) :
    def comment_count( self ) :
        return self.comment_set.count() # This line won't work.

    title = ....
    ....
```

I want to have `comment_count` so that I can get a count the comments in the admin page.

**EDIT:** For your convenience, here is the `models.py` for `django.contrib.comments`

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.comments.managers import CommentManager
from django.contrib.contenttypes import generic
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
from django.db import models
from django.core import urlresolvers
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.utils import timezone
from django.conf import settings

COMMENT_MAX_LENGTH = getattr(settings,'COMMENT_MAX_LENGTH',3000)

class BaseCommentAbstractModel(models.Model):
    """
    An abstract base class that any custom comment models probably should
    subclass.
    """

    # Content-object field
    content_type   = models.ForeignKey(ContentType,
            verbose_name=_('content type'),
            related_name="content_type_set_for_%(class)s")
    object_pk      = models.TextField(_('object ID'))
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey(ct_field="content_type", fk_field="object_pk")

    # Metadata about the comment
    site        = models.ForeignKey(Site)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def get_content_object_url(self):
        """
        Get a URL suitable for redirecting to the content object.
        """
        return urlresolvers.reverse(
            "comments-url-redirect",
            args=(self.content_type_id, self.object_pk)
        )

class Comment(BaseCommentAbstractModel):
    """
    A user comment about some object.
    """

    # Who posted this comment? If ``user`` is set then it was an authenticated
    # user; otherwise at least user_name should have been set and the comment
    # was posted by a non-authenticated user.
    user        = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name=_('user'),
                    blank=True, null=True, related_name="%(class)s_comments")
    user_name   = models.CharField(_("user's name"), max_length=50, blank=True)
    user_email  = models.EmailField(_("user's email address"), blank=True)
    user_url    = models.URLField(_("user's URL"), blank=True)

    comment = models.TextField(_('comment'), max_length=COMMENT_MAX_LENGTH)

    # Metadata about the comment
    submit_date = models.DateTimeField(_('date/time submitted'), default=None)
    ip_address  = models.IPAddressField(_('IP address'), blank=True, null=True)
    is_public   = models.BooleanField(_('is public'), default=True,
                    help_text=_('Uncheck this box to make the comment effectively ' \
                                'disappear from the site.'))
    is_removed  = models.BooleanField(_('is removed'), default=False,
                    help_text=_('Check this box if the comment is inappropriate. ' \
                                'A "This comment has been removed" message will ' \
                                'be displayed instead.'))

    # Manager
    objects = CommentManager()

    class Meta:
        db_table = "django_comments"
        ordering = ('submit_date',)
        permissions = [("can_moderate", "Can moderate comments")]
        verbose_name = _('comment')
        verbose_name_plural = _('comments')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s: %s..." % (self.name, self.comment[:50])

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.submit_date is None:
            self.submit_date = timezone.now()
        super(Comment, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def _get_userinfo(self):
        """
        Get a dictionary that pulls together information about the poster
        safely for both authenticated and non-authenticated comments.

        This dict will have ``name``, ``email``, and ``url`` fields.
        """
        if not hasattr(self, "_userinfo"):
            self._userinfo = {
                "name"  : self.user_name,
                "email" : self.user_email,
                "url"   : self.user_url
            }
            if self.user_id:
                u = self.user
                if u.email:
                    self._userinfo["email"] = u.email

                # If the user has a full name, use that for the user name.
                # However, a given user_name overrides the raw user.username,
                # so only use that if this comment has no associated name.
                if u.get_full_name():
                    self._userinfo["name"] = self.user.get_full_name()
                elif not self.user_name:
                    self._userinfo["name"] = u.username
        return self._userinfo
    userinfo = property(_get_userinfo, doc=_get_userinfo.__doc__)

    def _get_name(self):
        return self.userinfo["name"]
    def _set_name(self, val):
        if self.user_id:
            raise AttributeError(_("This comment was posted by an authenticated "\
                                   "user and thus the name is read-only."))
        self.user_name = val
    name = property(_get_name, _set_name, doc="The name of the user who posted this comment")

    def _get_email(self):
        return self.userinfo["email"]
    def _set_email(self, val):
        if self.user_id:
            raise AttributeError(_("This comment was posted by an authenticated "\
                                   "user and thus the email is read-only."))
        self.user_email = val
    email = property(_get_email, _set_email, doc="The email of the user who posted this comment")

    def _get_url(self):
        return self.userinfo["url"]
    def _set_url(self, val):
        self.user_url = val
    url = property(_get_url, _set_url, doc="The URL given by the user who posted this comment")

    def get_absolute_url(self, anchor_pattern="#c%(id)s"):
        return self.get_content_object_url() + (anchor_pattern % self.__dict__)

    def get_as_text(self):
        """
        Return this comment as plain text.  Useful for emails.
        """
        d = {
            'user': self.user or self.name,
            'date': self.submit_date,
            'comment': self.comment,
            'domain': self.site.domain,
            'url': self.get_absolute_url()
        }
        return _('Posted by %(user)s at %(date)s\n\n%(comment)s\n\nhttp://%(domain)s%(url)s') % d

class CommentFlag(models.Model):
    """
    Records a flag on a comment. This is intentionally flexible; right now, a
    flag could be:

        * A "removal suggestion" -- where a user suggests a comment for (potential) removal.

        * A "moderator deletion" -- used when a moderator deletes a comment.

    You can (ab)use this model to add other flags, if needed. However, by
    design users are only allowed to flag a comment with a given flag once;
    if you want rating look elsewhere.
    """
    user      = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name=_('user'), related_name="comment_flags")
    comment   = models.ForeignKey(Comment, verbose_name=_('comment'), related_name="flags")
    flag      = models.CharField(_('flag'), max_length=30, db_index=True)
    flag_date = models.DateTimeField(_('date'), default=None)

    # Constants for flag types
    SUGGEST_REMOVAL = "removal suggestion"
    MODERATOR_DELETION = "moderator deletion"
    MODERATOR_APPROVAL = "moderator approval"

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'django_comment_flags'
        unique_together = [('user', 'comment', 'flag')]
        verbose_name = _('comment flag')
        verbose_name_plural = _('comment flags')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s flag of comment ID %s by %s" % \
            (self.flag, self.comment_id, self.user.username)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.flag_date is None:
            self.flag_date = timezone.now()
        super(CommentFlag, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Comments are related to your Models via [generic relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations) so you can look up the comments for your object as you would any generic relation:

```
from django.conrtib.comments.models import Comment
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
class Blog( models.Model ) :
    def comment_count(self) :
        ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Blog)
        obj_pk = self.id
        return Comment.objects.filter(content_type=ct,object_pk=obj_pk).count()
```